# Applying material to a cube

Tags: modeling, materials

I don't speak English well, I hope you will understand me. I'm new to Blender and I'm facing a problem. Thank you all for the answers! When I apply the material to my object, the drawing on the upper face deforms. The grinding pattern turns out to be circular. Are there ways to fix this and make the drawing straight?

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kzv3I1GJEa-bB55tECPBfMbk0gaaJm0J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the *Anisotropic* deformation put the value at 0 in this *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

As for the brushed metal texture, your material is super complicated, you have the same result with the following setup: *(Input) Texture Coordinate (UV* output) > *Mapping* node (squeezed on X) > *Noise Texture* (put the Scale at 200 or more) > *ColorRamp* (darken the white needle if you want to make it more reflective) > *Principled BSDF* (with *Metallic* at 1):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it can be a solution. But I meant the scratch pattern itself. It becomes round on horizontal faces. Are there any ways to fix this? I tried to rotate the axes of a particular face, but it didn't work out.

Comment: I found the solution and lost it, but your material is uselessly complicated, I would do something much simpler, just plug a Noise into the Roughness and squeez it, I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: Thank you very much! You've helped me out a lot

Answer (score 3):

if you change the texture coordinates to UV, mute the length node and give some y scale, you get this:

[image]

Hopefully this is what you want.