# how to set up brushed aluminium node material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to achieve an aluminium texture for my object. I have the following node set up, Im facing 2 problems. On the top of my cube, there's a rounded aluminium, and on the other sides, the aluminium has straight lines, as I want it to be.

The other problem is, the aluminium has too organic lines, and doesn't look natural, like the example photo I have included (silver aluminium). I'm going to render with cycles engine for this material if this node set up needs to meet cycles requirements.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310408/applying-material-to-a-cube/310409#310409

Comment: Thank you Moonboots, worked well, the only thing I added was a bump node going into the normal.