# Same material from Blenderkit gives different result from EEVEE and Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, blenderkit

I have applied a texture from Blenderkit to the default cube. The lights and world is the same.
When I render in EEVEE the material is more visible than Cycles render, the material is almost not visible in Cycles. Is there something I need to tweak to get the same results like in EEVEE?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Don't forget to pack the images

Comment: Here's the Blender file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=6BYN07ap" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/6BYN07ap/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it reminds me [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310408/applying-material-to-a-cube/310409#310409). I'm not sure why your material is so complicated for a simple brushed metal, I propose a simpler one in the linked page.

As for the difference between Eevee and Cycles it's probably because *Anisotropic* (in Blender 4 it's now in the *Principled BSDF* under *Specular*) works in Cycles but not in Eevee, so in Cycles you'll have a deformation of the reflection that you won't have in Eevee:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking at my file, but its not my material. Its from BlenderKit- Add-on.

Comment: OK but I gave the probable explanation, the difference comes from the Anisotropic

Comment: Thanks for your help as always Moonboots!